# Adding a column of lag variables between 2 data frames in R

Tags: r, time-series, lag

I have two time series data frames with the same dates (lets say the data frames are called df1 and df2). I want to add multiple columns to df1 that have the lagged valeus from df2

I have tried the lag function, but it only will print out 1 lag in 1 column.

Creating 2 data frames

```
Date <-  seq.Date(as.Date("2004-01-01"), as.Date("2004-01-06"), by ="day")

df1 <- data.frame(
  Date,
  Price = sample(c(1:9), length(Date), replace = TRUE))

df2 <- data.frame(
  Date,
  Catch = c(sample(c(1:100), 2, replace = TRUE), NA,
            sample(c(1:100), 2, replace = TRUE), NA))
```

My df1 and df2 look like,

```
>df1
       Date     Price
>1 2004-01-01     2
>2 2004-01-02     4
>3 2004-01-03     7
>4 2004-01-04     9
>5 2004-01-05     6
>6 2004-01-06     9

>df2
       Date    Catch
>1 2004-01-01    95
>2 2004-01-02    14
>3 2004-01-03    NA
>4 2004-01-04   100
>5 2004-01-05    87
>6 2004-01-06    NA
```

I have tried to use the lag function:

```
df1$lag_catch_01 <- lag(df2$Catch, k = 1)
```

which gives me:

```
       Date     Price lag_catch
>1 2004-01-01     2        NA
>2 2004-01-02     4        95
>3 2004-01-03     7        14
>4 2004-01-04     9        NA
>5 2004-01-05     6       100
>6 2004-01-06     9        87
```

But I really want an output like this:

```
       Date      Price lag_catch_01 lag_catch_02
>1 2004-01-01     2           NA           NA
>2 2004-01-02     4           95           NA
>3 2004-01-03     7           14           95
>4 2004-01-04     9           NA           14
>5 2004-01-05     6          100           NA
>6 2004-01-06     9           87          100
```

I guess I could use the lag functions multiple times like this:

```
df1$lag_catch_01 <- lag(df2$Catch, k = 1)
df1$lag_catch_02 <- lag(df2$Catch, k = 2)
```

But if I wanted to make 20 columns, each with 20 day lags that would become very exhausting.

Comment: Even seeding the data, I cannot even reproduce your first `lag`: https://rextester.com/SYWJQ89280. Your example may not be actual time series objects or you are using a package that masks `stats::lag`.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the lags in their own data.frame using `plyr` and then combine them:

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% bind_cols(data.frame(t(ldply(1:4, lag, x= (df2$Catch)))))
```

So `ldply(1:4, lag, x= (df2$Catch)` is say for the list (l in ldply) 1:4 apply the function lag and return a data.frame (d in ldply) with other named arguments at the end. The rest is just tidying up as in this case the data.frame created is the wrong way around

Comment: This worked!! so the 1:4 in the ldply function will indicate how many lags (and how many added columns) you want?  So if i wanted 20 lag columns, i would change that to 1:20?

Comment: Yep that's exactly it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those two lags work as you intend but need to dynamically extend number of lags, simply assign new columns to a matrix output with `sapply`:

```
df1[paste0("lag_catch_", 1:20)] <- sapply(1:20, function(i) lag(df2$Catch, k = i))
```